# Unable to deploy CefSharp application

Tags: c#, deployment, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I'm trying to run my CefSharp application on a separate computer other than my development machine, but I'm unable to. I built it in Release for the x64 platform, and moved the entire contents of the build folder over to my other computer. I tried running all the executables in the build folder, but none of them would work; when executed, they would not appear on screen, and after some time a window would open up with the generic "this program has stopped working" windows crash dialogue. I tried installing the Visual C++ redistributable and the .NET 4.5 Framework, but it still wouldn't run afterwards. What am I missing?

Comment: Is the other PC also 64-bit? What version of .NET are you targeting? Does the other machine have all of your dependencies available?

Comment: It is also 64 bit. What do you mean by version of .NET? and what dependencies?

Comment: How have you written an entire C# application without knowing what .NET is? It's Microsoft .NET, it's the framework that your application is using to run. If you're using Visual Studio go to Project > Properties > Application and see what the Target Framework is. If you're in Visual Studio look on the right and you'll have a folder for References. Highlight each one and in the Properties make sure Copy Local is true. Now try redeploying the app.

Comment: Christ man, you don't have to be so rude, I know what .NET is. I'm just not the experienced, seasoned and well-trained developer you seem to see yourself as. Give me a break.

Comment: The target framework is 4.5, by the way. Not 4, not 4.6, not 4.5.1. I installed 4.5 on the other machine.

Comment: Apologies, didn't intend to be rude. I was just genuinely curious. Did you see if the references were set to copy local?

Comment: Okay, I made sure all references were local copy.

Comment: Try to rebuild and redeploy the application again. If it's still not working then let us know does happen.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101097/discussion-between-maurdekye-and-equalsk).

Comment: I rebuilt the application and copied the files over again, but I am still getting the same error.